# Specify QUnit module when run with Grunt

Tags: testing, qunit, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt, PhantomJS, and the "watch" plugin to run my QUnit tests while I develop (separate from CI). I'd like to be able to focus on a specific QUnit module while I'm working on the code that that module's tests are focused on. When running QUnit in the browser I can specify a module to run (versus all tests).

So the question is, can I tell the Grunt qunit task to only run a certain module? I'm thinking a command line argument so that I don't have to change my Gruntfile, something like:

```
~$ grunt qunit --module="test this stuff, test that stuff"
```

**UPDATE**

To be clear, what I want to run are modules created in a test suite using QUnit's `module()` method:

```
module( "group a" );
test( "a basic test example", function() {
    ok( true, "this test is fine" );
});
test( "a basic test example 2", function() {
    ok( true, "this test is fine" );
});

module( "group b" );
test( "a basic test example 3", function() {
    ok( true, "this test is fine" );
});
test( "a basic test example 4", function() {
    ok( true, "this test is fine" );
});
```

In the example above, this code is all in one test suite, but in the resulting html test file I get a drop down to run either module "group a" or module "group b" (through QUnit's UI). What I want is to be able to specify, programmatically, that I want to run a specific module through the `grunt qunit` task.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your config for grunt-qunit like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  qunit: {
    module1: {
      options: {
        urls: [
         'http://localhost:8000/test/module1/foo.html',
         'http://localhost:8000/test/module1/bar.html',
        ]
      }
    },
    module2: {
      options: {
        urls: [
         'http://localhost:8000/test/module2/foo.html',
         'http://localhost:8000/test/module2/bar.html',
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

You can run an individual module like `grunt qunit:module1`

Comment: While true, I was hoping to find something more generic. Basically, when I add a module to my test suite, I don't want to have to go create a new module target for it. Thanks for posting though.

Comment: Well, you can make a task that looks in `./test` and configs up a module for each subdirectory then queues them for execution, and takes a modules argument to filter on.

Comment: Yes, but I'm more referring to being able to run QUnit's `module`s. What you have here is the creation of different html test suites that act in that role. What I want though is to be able to run the module that is declared in the test suite, not a newly created html file.

Comment: That functionality doesn't seem to exist in grunt-contrib-qunit, so I think you'd have to submit a patch or feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I think a viable workaround could be to define a module filter option, and if it exist, append it to the urls.
Something like this in the Gruntfile.js

```
var moduleFilter =  '';
if (grunt.option('module')) {
  moduleFilter = '?module=' + grunt.option('module')
}
```

then using it:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  qunit: {
    options: {
        ...
        urls: [
          'http://localhost:3000/qunit' + moduleFilter
        ]
    }
  }
});
```

Note that this will work for one module only.
Maybe (but not tested) you can use the `filter` query param instead of module, 
and name your modules to match the filter, in order to be able to group them.

Note: Running multiple modules is not something that QUnit will support.

**References:**

- https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/426
- https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit/issues/31 (seems like you are the OP... grumpf)

Comment: That certainly looks like a more workable solution, I'll try it out when I'm back on this project.